# Power BI: Please wait while we establish a connection to python

Tags: powerbi

I've reinstalled Python 3.11/windows and can't seem to have any luck running this script. I just get the "Please wait while we establish a connection to python" with the spinner window that never changes. Any ideas?

I've uninstalled/reinstalled Power BI. I can run the script in my Python IDE with no problems. I've no other version of Python running. I've got Python correctly set in my environment variables.

Here's the script:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import getpass
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook
username = getpass.getuser()
print(username)
if username.lower() == "xxxx":
    opra = (r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - xxxx\OPRA - Documents\Lessor Tracker\Lessor Tracking")
elif username.lower() == "xxxx":
    opra = (r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - xxxx\OPRA - Documents\Lessor Tracker\Lessor Tracking")

elif username.lower() == "xxxx":
    opra = (r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - xxxx\OPRA - Documents\Lessor Tracker\Lessor Tracking")

else:
    opra = (r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - xxxx\OPRA - Documents\Lessor Tracker\Lessor Tracking")
os.chdir(opra)
cwd = os.path.abspath(opra)
print(cwd)
files = os.listdir(opra)  

## Method 1 gets the first sheet of a given file
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    r=0    
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        print(file)
        wb = load_workbook(file) # use the actual path of your workbook
        ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Lessors') 
        data = []
        # iterate over all the rows in the sheet
        for row in ws: 
           if ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].hidden == False:
             row_values = [cell.value for cell in row]
             data.append(row_values)
             jd = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
             r=r+1
             wbn = str(file) + str(r)
             jd.insert(6,"Workbook",wbn,False)
    df = df.append(jd, ignore_index=False)
        
print(df)
```

This has really got me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

So just to update on the Python script issue i was having, it turns out that a Python script had to have no warnings in it in order to run correctly in Power BI.
I don't recall this ever being an issue in the past, a script would run through even if there were warnings. So even if it runs in an IDE and returns results but with warnings it will hang in Power BI and just sit there and eventually time out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI go to File - Options - Python Scripting and set your Python home directory.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes i have Python scripting set to my Python home directory

Comment: That's not true. 
You can try with `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')` you will still get nothing from Power BI